# Regex Expression to split a filter string based on first occurrence of allowed delimeter and fetch key,operator,value

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy

Currently I am working on a legacy code base to support filter for one of my REST API. Currently we support 3 Operator which are `:`  Equal, `!` Not Equal,`~` Like.Current code splits passed the filter String and creates a String array, based on a regex which finally contains `key`,`op`,`value`. If the string array size is not equal to 3, it throws an exception.

```
//String filter1="name:ALTAF"; // Splitting correctly of size 3
//String filter2="name~:PDF"; // Not Splitting correctly - Goes in catch block.
String filter3="effectiveStartDateTime:2019-07-25T07:00"; // Not Splitting correctly - Goes in catch block.
String[] filterArray = filter3.split("((?<=[!:~><])|(?=[!:~><]))");

if (filterArray.length == 3) {
     String key = filterArray[0].trim();
     String op = filterArray[1].trim();
     String value = filterArray[2].trim();
     System.out.println("filter key =>" + key);
     System.out.println("filter operator =>" +op);
     System.out.println("filter value =>"+ value);
     }
     else {
         //throw Exception for invalid filter criteria.
     }
```

For my filter Scenario , filter String which I pass is `effectiveStartDateTime:2019-07-25T07:00` which the current regex splits and gives a size more than 3 as it encounters `:` twice.

I have changed the regex to include a limit .

```
String[] filterArray = filter3.split("((?<=[!:~><])|(?=[!:~><]))",3);
```

Which splits the filter string correctly => Key– `effectiveStartDateTime` , Operator- `:` , Value- `2019-07-24T07:00`

So what I tried to do on top is split the regex based on the first occurrence of the allowed operators(`:` `!` `~`) present in the filter string and if the obtained string array size is more than 3 throw exception as usual.

But it fails in one negative scenario where I pass the filter string as- `name~:PDF` where I get below 
key– `name` , Operator- `~` , value- `:PDF`

where instead of giving the size as 4 it gives 3 and it passes. But what I want is, split the filter string based on the allowed operators(: ! ~) and in this case , i should get size as 4.

Could anyone guide me on the same.

Cheers
Sam

Comment: You probably need to remove `3` argument passed to `split`

Comment: Edited the question @ Wiktor Stribiżew . I have added `3` to split the effectiveStartDateTime filter string correctly. But it gives size as 3 for the other string also now like - `name~:PDF` which is not correct.

Comment: So i want to achieve the following . String filter1="name:ALTAF" => key- `name `, operator- `:` value- `ALTAF`.String filter2="effectiveStartDateTime:2019-07-25T07:00"; => key- `effectiveStartDateTime` , operator- `:` value- `2019-07-25T07:00`.String filter3="name~:MNO" => size should come as 4 and should fail as two operators have appeared here once.

Comment: Whats the difference between case 2 and 3? If the value can be anything and this _anything_ can contain the operator you must define when it is appropriate to split multiple times and when it's not. Currently there is just one example, thats not enough to clarify the intention.

Comment: @Burdui let's take case 2- String filter3="name~:PDF". Here i have occurrence of both `~` and `:`. So in this case , i want the size to be more than 3 as two out of three allowed operators ( `:`  `! ` `~`) are present along with key and value. Again Case3 String filter2="effectiveStartDateTime:2019-07-25T07:00"; Here size should come as 3 with key- `effectiveStartDateTime` , operator- `:` value- `2019-07-25T07:00`. as i am splitting on the occurrence of allowed operator `:` which is present only once.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can achieve this with a `split`.
However if you still want to utilise regex you can use `Matcher`s.

In the following example i define a static pattern whcih can be used multiple times.
I am going to match the complete input string.
Multiple uses of the first operator are allowed.
If however an other operator occurs the group `other` will be matcher and thus not be null.
The other strings can be accessed via named capturing groups.

```
static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?<key>.*?)(?<op>[:~!])(?<value>(?:[^:~!]|\\k<op>)*+)(?<other>.+)?$");
public static void interpret(String filter){
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(filter);
    if(!matcher.matches()){
        throw new RuntimeException("invalid input");
    }
    if(matcher.group("other") != null){
        throw new RuntimeException("multiple operators");
    }
    String key = matcher.group("key").trim();
    String op = matcher.group("op").trim();
    String value = matcher.group("value").trim();
    System.out.printf("key=\"%s\", op=\"%s\", value=\"%s\"\n", key, op, value);
}
```